# reading rss feeds in applescript

Tags: rss, applescript

how do I read RSS feeds in apple script? I want it to pick and speakout latest news along with reading weather info

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to script an rss reader like NetNewsWire or even Safari.  The second easiest way is to write it in Ruby or Python and call Applescript stuff using Appscript.  Python has robust rss reading and parsing routines.  Dealing with a lot of text processing in Applescript is painful.  The third choice is to use an rss OSAX.  There was one at http://osaxen.com but it appears down right now.

Answer (score 0):

Satimage has a free osax (scripting addition) with xml capability. That would be a way to go.